# Keeping activity state when rotating screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to keep the state of the application when rotating the screen, but it's giving an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23xDu.png)

I tried using the android method onSaveInstanceState and onCreate to retrieve the state, but it is giving an error, I hope I can keep the data without configuring anything in the manifest, is it possible to save the state without using the manifest?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before we can answer your question, please provide more code and more explanation. Because, assuming your code that i see, you got the error due to accessing the array list inside savedstatebundle which can be null but you force it to be not null by casting it into array list, thats why the error says nullpointerexception because you are forcing the system to turn something that is not exist into an existing array list

Comment: I found the "problem", apparently I used the wrong method, when calling the onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) method with just one parameter it worked now.

Comment: By changing the view now to landscape the data keeps its state saved, thanks for trying to help ;)